# Unicorn and Gemfile are using different ruby versions when trying to run unicorn and Nginx on Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn, ruby-2.0, digital-ocean, ruby-2.1

I am trying to run my Rails app through Nginx and Unicorn and when I try to run `service unicorn start` it tells me I fail with `master failed to start, check stderr log for details`. My Gemfile specifies ruby 2.0.0 and my ruby versions is 2.0.0p353. Unicorn seems to be using ruby 2.1.3. Is there any way to have unicorn use ruby 2.0.0 if it came default using 2.1.3.

When I tail the unicorn log:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:294:in `join'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
E, [2014-10-31T20:55:57.551794 #15567] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 30319 exit 1> worker=1
I, [2014-10-31T20:55:57.552041 #15567]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2014-10-31T20:55:57.553188 #30329]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=30329
I, [2014-10-31T20:55:57.560300 #30331]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=30331
I, [2014-10-31T20:55:57.587723 #30329]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2014-10-31T20:55:57.595703 #30331]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2014-10-31T20:55:57.940679 #30325] ERROR -- : Your Ruby version is 2.1.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

It looks like the error may be stemming from unicorn being located in `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/` and my other gems in `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/`.

My unicorn.conf looks like:

```
worker_processes 4
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/rails"
pid "/home/unicorn/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"
```

My unicorn file `/etc/init.d` looks like:

````
set -e
NAME=unicorn
DESC="Unicorn web server"

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ -f /etc/default/unicorn ]; then
  . /etc/default/unicorn
fi

PID=${PID-/run/unicorn.pid}

run_by_init() {
    ([ "${previous-}" ] && [ "${runlevel-}" ]) || [ "${runlevel-}" = S ]
}

exit_with_message() {
  if ! run_by_init; then
    log_action_msg "$1 Not starting."
  fi
  exit 0
}

check_config() {
  if [ $CONFIGURED != "yes" ]; then
    exit_with_message "Unicorn is not configured (see /etc/default/unicorn)."
  fi
}

check_app_root() {
  if ! [ -d $APP_ROOT ]; then
    exit_with_message "Application directory $APP_ROOT is not exist."
  fi
}

set -u
```
And the start function in that file:
```
  start)
        check_config
        check_app_root

        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" $NAME || true
        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- $UNICORN_OPTS; then
          log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
          log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
              ;;
````

Followed by the other commands like restart, stop, and so on.

And my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.4.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.5.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.0'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'pg'
gem 'notes-cli'
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
gem 'gon'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'mailcatcher'
  gem 'rails-erd'
  gem 'annotate'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '2.4.3'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'email_spec'
end
```

I'd appreciate any help. I am new to Digital Ocean, Unicorn, and Nginx, with my only experience
in "deploying" is using Heroku.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if this is the right way, but here how I solved the problem:

1. Kill all acitve unicorn processes. Do `ps aux | grep unicorn` and then `kill -9 pid_number`
2. Change the ruby version in `/etc/default/unicorn` as per [How To Use the 1-Click Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 14.04 Image](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-1-click-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-image). In particular this part:

> PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/home/unicorn/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:$ export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3 export
>   GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3
>   DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/unicorn

3. Change the ruby version in `/etc/init.d/unicorn`, in particular this part:

> export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1 export
>   GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems

In my quotations the ruby versions don't match, because the one quote is from the article and the other is from my actual file, but just make sure that in all places you have the particular ruby version that you like.

4. Start unicorn: `service unicorn start`.

This assumes, you have already ran `bundle install` and have all necessary gems.

Comment: THis got me back on track after upgrading to rails 5 and ruby 2.4.1.